# How to stop recording after x minutes of silence in Audacity?

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording, audacity

I am using Audacity to record sound from webinar recordings. 
There could be a few minutes of silence during the webinar.

I want to set up Audacity to stop recording

- the best would be after, let's say,
  one hour when the silence is longer than five minutes. 
  Because I do know how long the webinar is.
- or just after *x* minutes of silence.

Is that possible to set up in the current version of Audacity (v2.0.3)? 
If not, is there any other way I can do an unattended recording
of an audio segment whose (approximate) length I know in advance,
without risking cutting off before it ends or recording hours of silence?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: I know that you don’t have VTC (vote-to-close) privilege yet, but you do have the privilege to flag questions (and, for that matter, to *ask* them), so you should have some idea of [what questions are on-topic for Super User](/help/on-topic) and what are not. The last sentence of this question was a classic example of **asking for a product … recommendation**. If you’re going to edit a question that is off-topic, you should fix the off-topic reason, and not just fix editorial problems like spelling (excessive abbreviation of words), punctuation and grammar.

Comment: P.S. You missed a couple abbreviations of words (“hr” and “mins”).

Comment: High-reputation users who approved Steven’s suggested edit:  I can’t @-ping you, but shame on you too.